# Is it possible to send a email with input fields in the mail body and get response?

Tags: outlook

I want to get feedback from the user through mailer component. So, I am planning to keep input fields in the mail body and get the response back and store it in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The best what you can do is to use the voting options in Outlook. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [Create polls in email messages and review the results](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-polls-in-email-messages-and-review-the-results-4d10e079-8ea1-489a-a79c-18cb71ae12dd)
- [Use Voting buttons in Outlook](http://kb.mcgill.ca/?portalid=2&articleid=1080#tab:homeTab:crumb:8:artId:1080:src:article)

The Outlook object model provides the [VotingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingoptions?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1363)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) property which allows setting a String specifying a delimited string containing the voting options for the mail message. This property uses the character specified in the value name, `sList`, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple voting options.

In replies, you can use the [VotingResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingresponse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1364)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) property which returns or sets a String specifying the voting response for the mail message.

Also, you may consider sending a link in the message body to a web page where users may enter all the required responses.